How to test observable that emits multiple times on subscription in jasmine angular framework
I am having a service product.service.ts
class ProductService {

public product$: Observable<string> = from(['prod1','prod2','prod3','prod4']);

<other methods goes here...>

}

I want to test the below cases?

products$ observable should emit all the four values
third emitted data should be prod3


We can achieve this using jasmine.spy
it('should emit respective products'){
    const productsSpy = jasmine.createSpy();

    service.products$.subscribe(productsSpy);

    expect(productsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);
    expect(productsSpy.calls.argsFor(2)[0]).toBe('prod3');

}


You can test it using the rxjs operator toArray(), which collects all the emits to an array.
it("should emit third value as 'prod3'", (done) => {
    service.product$.pipe(toArray()).subscribe((data: any) => {
        expect(data.length).toEqual(4);
        expect(data[2]).toEqual('prod3');
        done();
    });
});

